# grid reconfigure issue with rowexpander plugin extjs 4.21

Tags: extjs4.2

I am experiencing an issue when I reconfigure my grid which has a rowexpander plugin in it. If I remove the plugin it is working fine. I tried the below fix too but no luck

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpander, {
     beforeReconfigure: function (grid, store, columns, oldStore, oldColumns) {              
                var expander = this.getHeaderConfig();
                expander.locked = true;
                if (columns)
                    columns.unshift(expander);
            }
        });
```

This is the error thown

Unhandled exception at line 9988, column 13 in script block

0x80070057 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid argument.

It was thrown from the below location of the extjs script block

```
onColumnsChanged: function(headerCt) {
    var items = this.view.el.query(this.rowBodyTdSelector),
        colspan = headerCt.getVisibleGridColumns().length,
        len = items.length,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        items[i].colSpan = colspan; // **the error thown location is this**
    }
},
```

Please help ! Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3):

```
grid.suspendEvents();
grid.reconfigure (store);
grid.resumeEvents();
```

Comment: Try providing a little explanation too.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a bit too late, but anyway..

Can you confirm it only happens in IE? Mozilla and Chrome seem to be ok with it.

Apparently IE doesn't like `colspan=0`, and at some point the code tries to assign 0 to the colSpan property of the item and the error is thrown.

I've tried changing it to `items[i].colSpan = colspan || 1;` and the problem was solved, but of course this is not a solution. I'm trying to check if this is a real bug or just lack of knowledge! :)

EDIT:
Although I couldn't find any solution, to make it work I just overridden the method using `Ext.override` and left it that way.


EDIT2:

 As proposed by `ojintoad`, you can also use something like `.setAttribute('colSpan', 1);`, to change the colspan value from 0 to 1.

Comment: I don't know if it is a better solution, but setAttribute('colSpan', colspan); worked for me.  I only experienced this in IE10 so only applied this to that browser version in my override.  Thanks for confirming this exists, I don't see any entries on Ext's forums.

Comment: I didn't see any reference to this as well, so just had to dig into it myself. Yes, that would be a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below override

```
 overrideRowBodyOnColumnChanged: function () {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < this.features.length; i++) {
            if (this.features[i].ftype == 'rowbody') {
                Ext.override(this.features[i], {
                    onColumnsChanged: function (headerCt) {
                        var items = this.view.el.query(this.rowBodyTdSelector),
                            colspan = headerCt.getVisibleGridColumns().length,
                            len = items.length,
                            i;
                        colspan = colspan == 0 ? 1 : colspan;
                        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                            items[i].colSpan = colspan;
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    },
```

and call this override function in the initComponent function of the grid

```
initComponent: function () {

// your code

  this.overrideRowBodyOnColumnChanged();

}
```